# How to ad html tag inside trans directive in magento2

Tags: magento2, translate

I am trying to add a `<span>` tag inside a trans directive but, it is not working for me.

Below is what I am trying:

```
<h1 class="section-heading order-number-heading">{{trans 'Your Invoice <span class="number">#%invoice_id</span> for Order <span class="number">#%order_id</span>' invoice_id=$invoice.increment_id order_id=$order.increment_id}}</h1>
```

The output I am getting for it is that the `<span>` becomes part of the text.

Your Invoice `<span class="number">#000000061</span>` for Order `<span class="number">#000000172</span>` ----> this is the output I get.

How can I add  tag inside trans directive so I can style specific parts of the text separately? I am doing all this in a custom email template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:-**

Just add " |raw " before closing trans( }} )

```
<h1 class="section-heading order-number-heading">{{trans 'Your Invoice <span class="number">#%invoice_id</span> for Order <span class="number">#%order_id</span>' invoice_id=$invoice.increment_id order_id=$order.increment_id|raw}}</h1>
```